# Get the Array Modifier Count when Fit length with Python

Tags: python, modifiers

I want to output a list of all my objects in a collection and how much of each there are.
But for this I need the number of how much the array modifier has added, but I dont see it when I use "Fit length" type.
Is there a way with python to get this number?

BR

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is exposed to the API but you can approximate it by calculating the curve length and dividing by the offset, but it will work only for simple arrays and you'll have to account for unapplied transforms if any...

Comment: @Gorgious so if I have to calculate it for every object I have, because they have different dimensions. Or is there an easy way to do it for every object at once?